# Can't find where this HTML is generated from

Tags: html

On [this page](http://axisindustrialsolutions.com.au/privacypolicy), at the very bottom left, is a footer link to the privacy policy generated by HTML:

```
<a href="/privacypolicy">Privacy Policy</a>
```

I have downloaded a backup of the live site, and have performed a search on every file/folder for `privacypolicy` or `Privacy Policy` and found no search results.

I have looked in CMS > Static Blocks & CMS > Widgets, and this code is not present there.

What possible other locations could this code be generated from?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the location of the link, it's just before the body closing tag.  Looking at the root templates i.e. `1column.phtml` you can see a call to `<?php echo $this->getAbsoluteFooter() ?>` in this position.  Finding this method in block class `Mage_Page_Block_Html` shows it to return the content of `Mage::getStoreConfig('design/footer/absolute_footer')`, thus you can conclude the content is most likely found in `system->config->design->footer->misc HTML`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried looking for just "privacypolicy" instead of the entire line of code?

Might also want to look at your layout see if anything is being placed before the body ends

```
<reference name="before_body_end">
```

Comment: You didn't read the question properly matey. :-)